# How to allow only text in textbox using jquery.validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to exclude usage of single quote and double quotes in my textbox. if user enters text with qutation i need to show error. How can i do it with jquery.validate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#elm').validate(
       {
            valid: function(inputValue){
                  return !inputValue.match(/['"]+/);
            }
});
```

Comment: i dont know how to use it. explain me.

Comment: Won't that match if it *does* have quotes?

Comment: Good point alex, changed it.  So that plugin lets you validate any input element on the page.  The function above tells the plugin to call the anonymous function in order to determine if the element with the id of 'elm' is valid or not.  You should replace 'elm' with the id of the element you are validating.

Comment: Your regex only needs the character class: `/['"]/`. There's no need for one or more when one will do. It still works though.

Comment: Ur Code is not understandable explain me by using addmethod

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression like ^[a-zA-Z]
This will accept only Characters from A-Z and a-z.

Here is the code:
Add a Method for Regular expression .

```
         $.validator.addMethod("regex",function(value,element,regexp){
                var re= new RegExp(regexp);
                return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
            },"Only Characters from A-z");
```

And then you need to add a rule on that field.

```
           rules:{
                    username:{
                        required:true,
                        regex:"^[a-zA-Z]+$" //Only Characters
                    }
                 },
           messages:{
                       username:{
                           required:"Mandatory"
                      }
                 },
```

thats it..